# Mongo C++ driver query() method is not getting all the results it should

Tags: c++, mongodb

I'm experiencing some weird behavior using query method with the Mongo C++ driver (legacy-1.0.2 version).

In particular, I have a given database (`orion`) (which some populated data inside) and a program that counts elements in a given collection (`entities`) of such database for a given query expression using four different methods:

- Count method
- Plain query (i.e without extra limit of skip parameters)
- Query using a limit greater than the maximun numbers of elements in the collection (I'm using 1000, and the colletion has 886 elements)
- Query using same limit and skip to 0

Program code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "mongo/client/dbclient.h" // for the driver

// Compilation hint: g++ example.cpp -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_regex -o example

using namespace mongo;

int main() {
  client::initialize();

  DBClientConnection c;
  std::auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor;
  c.connect("localhost");

  BSONObj q = BSON("_id.servicePath" << BSON ( "$in" << BSON_ARRAY( "/qa_fermin") ) );

  int n1 = c.count("orion.entities", q);
  cursor = c.query("orion.entities", q);
  int n2 = cursor->itcount();
  cursor = c.query("orion.entities", q, 1000);
  int n3 = cursor->itcount();
  cursor = c.query("orion.entities", q, 1000, 0);
  int n4 = cursor->itcount();

  std::cout << "using count: "          << n1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "plain query: "          << n2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "query + limit: "        << n3 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "query + limit + skip: " << n4 << std::endl;
}
```

As far as I understand the result in all cases should be the same. However, this is the output I get:

```
using count: 307
plain query: 307
query + limit: 188
query + limit + skip: 188
```

It seems that the last two cases (query + limit and query + limit + skip) are retrieving less documents than expected.

As far as I understand the result should be the same in the 4 cases, no matter the query expression and the database, as long as the limit value is greater than the total numbers of document in the collection.

I have the "feeling" that it could be related with how cursor behaves in some way, but I'm not able to figure out how... Any idea which helps to understand this behaviour would be appreciated, please.

**EDIT:** I have "isolated" steps 2 and 3 and look MongoDB server log (verbosity level for the query subsystem set to 5). I'm adding the traces, just it case they could be useful (omitting prefix timestamp, to make them shorter):

In the case of plain query (the one which returns 307 results):

```
D QUERY    [conn108926] Enough for first batch, wantMore=1 ntoreturn=0 numResults=47
D QUERY    [conn108926] caching executor with cursorid 104197639043543 after returning 47 results
...
D QUERY    [conn108926] Running getMore, cursorid: 104197639043543
D QUERY    [conn108926] getMore saving client cursor ended with state ADVANCED
D QUERY    [conn108926] getMore returned 188 results
...
D QUERY    [conn108926] Running getMore, cursorid: 104197639043543
D QUERY    [conn108926] getMore NOT saving client cursor, ended with state IS_EOF
D QUERY    [conn108926] getMore returned 72 results
```

(It seems there is a first batch with 47, a second with 188 and a final with 72; 47 + 188 + 72 = 307)

In the case of query + limit (the one which wrongly returns 188):

```
D QUERY    [conn108927] Enough for first batch, wantMore=0 ntoreturn=1000 numResults=188
D QUERY    [conn108927] Not caching executor but returning 188 results.
```

(Only one batch, which size is curiosly the size of the scond batch in the "righ query" case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try upgrading to legacy-1.0.6 or newer? A bug related to cursor management was fixed in that release (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX-699)

Comment: I'd recommend upgrading to legacy-1.1.0, or legacy-1.0.7 if you don't want to make the jump to the legacy-1.1 series yet.